# Can't dismiss a notification on https://stackexchange.com

Tags: bug, notifications, stackexchange.com

When you receive a notification on https://stackexchange.com/, or in the network profile, you'll see the usual red note box:

[image]

But clicking the inbox icon and then clicking on a space away from it doesn't dismiss it.  It only disappears if you click a link to visit another page.

Comment: Cannot reproduce. Tried on https://stackexchange.com, and am able to close it by clicking away from it anywhere on the page.

Comment: @SonictheK-DayHedgehog Comment again?  I'm in the network profile right now.

Comment: Still unable to reproduce. Maybe it was fixed in a JS update, but your system still has older JS cached. Try clearing your browser's cache.

Comment: @SonictheK-DayHedgehog Nope, still doing it. And I cleared my cache and cookies before doing this.

Comment: The whole API seems super sketchy today. I too have a notification that has popped up several times that I couldn't dismiss, although this was entirely in the app. Once I visited the actual site and clicked the bell, it went away. On top of that, pages in the app will simply not load at some times, and comments will sometimes fail to post, regardless of network connection. I was thinking about making a post about it.